# Rails Date Picker for a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a data picker set up on my website at the moment (it drops down the calendar and allows me to choose the date which then gets put into the text box.)

However it isn't working when I click apply filters. I'm wanting it to only show the dates in the table within that range.

(in my controller, The def show)

```
params[:search] ||= {}
    params[:search][:meta_sort] ||= "id.desc"
    if params[:search]
      @start  =  params[:search]["date_searcher(1)"]
      @end    =  params[:search]["date_searcher(2)"]
    end
```

In my html

```
<div class="well">
  <h3 class="title">Dates</h3>
  <%= f.input :start_date do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "search[date_searcher(1)]", @start, :class => "date_picker" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :end_date do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "search[date_searcher(2)]", @end, :class => "date_picker" %>
  <% end %>

  <p>To search using dates enter in Start date/End date then select the search method.</p>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="well">
    <%= f.submit "Apply filters", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
```

Again pretty new to this so if i've missed anything let me know!